# Multi-repo Visual Studio Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, nuget

I have an ASP.NET Core API project and the solution currently has 4 other projects in it which are all class libraries i.e. `MyProject.Core`, `MyProject.Infrastructure`, `MyProject.Business` and `MyProject.Frontend`.

Because some of these class libraries are used in multiple projects, I went ahead and created them as separate projects and also created their separate GitHub repos. Finally, I set up each project repo with its GitHub action to create its NuGet package and upload it to my private registry.

My objective is to have a multi-repo solution for my ASP.NET Core API project so that I can make changes on the fly in any project and be able to debug the whole thing. When everything is working, I simply want to commit my changes which should push updates to each project's respective GitHub repo and generate their NuGet packages.

I want to point out that all interdependencies in my class library projects are handled through NuGet packages. For example, `MyProject.Infrastructure` uses the NuGet package for `MyProject.Core` and does NOT have a project reference to it. Project references are only at the ASP.NET API project level.

Here's where I'm confused and having some problems: As I just mentioned, my ASP.NET Core API project has "project references" to each of these individual projects -- not their NuGet packages. Although I can build each project successfully, when I try to build the API project, I end up getting a ton of errors for package dependencies and they all start with the same phrase. Here's one:

> Error NU1106  Unable to satisfy conflicting requests for
> 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect':
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect (>= 6.15.1) (via
> package/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer 7.0.5),
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect (>= 6.15.1) (via
> package/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect 7.0.5),
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect (>= 6.24.0) (via
> package/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.1.1),
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect (>= 6.24.0) (via
> package/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.1.1) Framework:
> (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)    MyProject.API   C:\Users\sam\source\repos\MyProject.API\MyProject.API\MyProject.API\MyProject.API.csproj    1

Here's what the project file looks like for `MyProject.API`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.5" NoWarn="NU1605" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="7.0.5" NoWarn="NU1605" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.SignalR" Version="1.21.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\MyProject.Business\MyProject.Business\MyProject.Business\MyProject.Business.csproj" />
      <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\MyProject.Core\MyProject.Core\MyProject.Core\MyProject.Core.csproj" />
      <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\MyProject.Frontend\MyProject.Frontend\MyProject.Frontend\MyProject.Frontend.csproj" />
      <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\..\MyProject.Infrastructure\MyProject.Infrastructure\MyProject.Infrastructure\MyProject.Infrastructure.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

What am I doing wrong here? The idea is to have a multi-repo solution for my ASP.NET Core API project while maintaining each class library project in its separate GitHub repo.

P.S. This is where I think I may have conflicting objectives:

- I do want each class library project to use the NuGet packages of its dependencies e.g. `MyProject.Core` so that all my class libraries are completely reusable without any internal project references.
- I also want to be able to open one solution and add/modify code in any of these projects and debug it without having to worry about generating updated NuGet packages.

I think there's a conflict here because `MyProject.Business` uses the NuGet package for `MyProject.Core` and if I update the code in `MyProject.Core`, the `MyProject.Business` still wants to use the NuGet package for `MyProject.Core` and not necessarily the updated code in the solution.

Am I making a mistake here in creating a multi-repo solution or do I have conflicting goals?

Comment: Why are you making this sort of architecture in the first place? What advantage do you think that splitting up the dependencies into separate NuGet packages is going to give you?

Comment: Two reasons: we have several projects that use different combinations of these projects. For example an Azure Functions project uses both the `Core` and the `Infrastructure` while a .NET MAUI project uses the `Core` and the `Frontend`. Second reason is the separate teams. They're in different parts of the world and we want them to have access to only what they need. Creating individual NuGet packages and making them available through our private registry, serves both purposes.

Comment: If your interdependencies are handled via NuGet packages (ex MyProject.Infrastructure references MyProject.Core via NuGet), then why do we see direct project references from MyProject.API to both .csprojs for Infrastructure and Core? Now you're depending on Core via both NuGet and .csproj reference, making for a mess. Your API should refer to its dependencies via the same NuGet packages that your other class libraries are referring to them.

Comment: You're exactly right. This is what I was talking about in the PS section of my original post.

Comment: You can have a single solution build several nugets. In fact, that's even the default, and VS builds a nuget for every csproj (if instructed to create packages). The dependency handling will work correctly, even if you have project references within your solution.

Comment: @PMF I didn't realize that. The only thing I need to figure out is the `yaml` file for my  GitHub actions. I'll give that a try. Thanks!